# Bxslider not firing

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, bxslider

please tell me why I can't get the bxplayer to work. I've tried the simplest example and still nothing.

I used the js and css directly from the site.

```
<script src="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
<link href="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

And this is the html

```
<ul class="bxslider">
<li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/tree_root.jpg" title="Funky roots" /></li>
<li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_road.jpg" title="The long and winding road" /></li>
<li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/trees.jpg" title="Happy trees" /></li>
```

```
<script>$('.bxslider').bxSlider({ mode: 'fade', captions: true});</script>
```

The [website](http://consplan.studyor.net/) is here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

I was putting the bxslider calls before the

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

Once I moved them after, everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a Jquery.js too, and you will have something like this in your `<head>` :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
<link href="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

This is a example:

http://jsfiddle.net/4XjGf/

Comment: And if you have a Jquery.js in your web site and its not work make u sure de script whit Jquery.js is in the top of your scripts.

Comment: I do have jquery in my theme, the latest one 2.0.3 even. And the weird part is that another plugin slider works fine.

Comment: Found the problem, I had to put the bxslider calls after the <?php wp_head(); ?>